# D3.js transition multiple lines - data doesn't update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I'm trying to get my multiple line graph to update when I filter the data. But, while the axis are transitioning as they should, my lines are updated with the old unfiltered data; causing it to go beyond the chart area. My problem seems to be the transition part but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have working examples when the y-axis stays the same, but not with this type of changing data. I could, I think, remove all the old paths but as far as I can discern I should be able to just update as long as we don't need to add more lines?

Here is a working jsFiddle instead of the old wall o' code. It's a more simple graph than the code I posted earlier but the basic problem is the same. The line(s) don't update.

Testcode:

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {

Arr1 = [{Antal:3000,Datum:parseDate("2008-03-30")},{Antal:2000,Datum:parseDate("2008-06-30")}];
Arr2 = [{Antal:5000,Datum:parseDate("2008-03-30")},{Antal:8300,Datum:parseDate("2008-06-30")}];

data = Arr1.concat(Arr2)
dsMainArr = [{name: "primary",values:Arr1},{name: "specialist",values:Arr2}];


 // redraw the line
    city
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", null);

    //update x domain for axis labels
    y.domain([
        d3.min(dsMainArr, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.Antal; }); }),
        d3.max(dsMainArr, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.Antal; }); })
      ]);


    //slide xAxis       
   svg.select(".y.axis")
            .transition()
            .duration(300)
            .ease("linear")
            .call(yAxis);

    //slide the line to the left 
    city.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

});
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/1x0k3Lzd/34/](http://jsfiddle.net/1x0k3Lzd/28/)

Any idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: What I don't really get is how the updated data isn't passed? I've checked the objects I created in the console log and I've got new data points bound  but to use that to redraw the graph seems beyond the code. Shouldn't this be quite easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
city
.attr("d", line)
.attr("transform", null);
```

and

```
 city.transition()
   .duration(500)
   .ease("linear")
   .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
   .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

You need something like

```
city
.data(dsMainArr)
.select('.line')
.transition()
.duration(500)
.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

You need to include `data(dsMainArr)` again as you've redefined `dsMainArr` locally.

As an aside, note

```
d3.select('input[type=button]').on("click", function(){})
```

functions as

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){})
```

Here is a link to the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47xnn07h/2/

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but it might been that I didn't set it up correctly. I think I tried with the data separate from line and transition. Anyways, thx, that worked like a charm :)